# How to print specific rows in a CSV files which have a specific value in a specific column?

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python. I have a CSV file which I want to print specific row from it I'd appreciate it if you could give me guidance. for example below table I want to print a Row if record Number is 2:
[This image shows an example of my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbHD.png)

I have below code as starter which prints out the headers:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    first = next(reader)
    print(first[0].split(','))
    for row in filename:
        print()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can explain a bit more where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

your example code seems somewhat confused, I presume the file is actually comma separated not tab delimited.  otherwise you wouldn't need to do the `first[0].split(',')`.

assuming that's the case, maybe something like this would work:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # skip header row
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[0]) == 2:
            print(row)
```

if you're after a specific row number, you could use `enumerate` to count rows and print when you get to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop check if the record number, which is the 0th column, is == 2:

```
for row in file:
    if row[0] == 2:
        print(row)
```

Comment: what if a cell value spans multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

**import pandas as pd**

#if you haven't installed it yet, you may go to terminal

#type this in terminal -> pip install pandas

**df = "O:\Documents\Animals.csv"**
#the location of your file on your pc

**rf = pd.read_csv(df)**
#read the csv file using pandas library

**user_input = input("Enter Category: ")**
#you may set a constant value or get user input, but in this case let's get user input

print(rf[rf['Specie'] == user_input][['Group Name']].values)
#use this format below

#rf[rf['what column do you search']][['column you want to get']].values

#we will be using .values to get the accurate value inside the column so

#it won't return false and true value